# Export data records from filemaker pro 16 with all strings quoted with ""

Tags: filemaker

Is it possible to export data records from filemaker and have all strings be in a "" quote? With string I mean type = text. Numbers shouldn't change though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no option I'm aware of that provides this behavior when exporting.

The `fieldType()` function may be helpful.
https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/fieldtype.html

Or, just create a single calc field "row" with all of the fields you want included - with appending quotes around the text fields - and do a .tab export of "rows" instead. That's generally how I handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If you export as CSV, this is the default behaviour as long as you do not export the "Apply current layout’s data formatting..." setting enabled.

Comment: I exported the records as you recommended but it puts also on numbers the "" quote.

Comment: That seems like a bug, maybe a locale issue. According to the documentation [here](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Fcomma-separated-text-format.html%23), it should work. _"Quotation marks enclose all field values, except unformatted numbers."_

Comment: Sorry my suggestion didn't work, there are some ideas you may want to try here at the FileMaker community [forum](https://community.filemaker.com/thread/154205). If you know XML, you can tailor make your exporting also using XSL. It is also possible that exporting as Excel and reexporting from Excel provides the result you need. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
To strip the quotes from the .csv, I open the .csv in Excel and save the file in Excel as a .csv.
This strips the double quotes.